# Does Ruby provide a way to do File.read() with specified encoding?

Tags: ruby, file, encoding

In ruby 1.9.x, we can specify the encoding with `File.open('filename','r:iso-8859-1')`. I often prefer to use a one-line File.read() if I am reading many short files into strings directly. Is there a way I can specify the encoding directly, or do I have to resort to one of the following?

```
str = File.read('filename')
str.force_encoding('iso-8859-1')
```

or

```
f = File.open('filename', 'r:iso-8859-1')
s = ''
while (line = f.gets)
    s += line
end
f.close
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-read):

> **read(name, [length [, offset]], open_args) → string**
>
> Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given `offset`, then returns `length` bytes (defaulting to the rest of the file). `read` ensures the file is closed before returning.
>
> If the last argument is a hash, it specifies option for internal open().

So you can say things like this:

```
s = File.read('pancakes', :encoding => 'iso-8859-1')
s.encoding
#<Encoding:ISO-8859-1>
```