# File.readlines invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby

I am processing a file which contains data from the web and encounter **invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)** error on certain log files.

```
a = File.readlines('log.csv').grep(/watch\?v=/).map do |s|
s = s.parse_csv;
{ timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3] }
end
puts a
```

I am trying to get this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873922/514070) working. I have seen people doing

`.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace)`

but it doesnt appear to work with `File.readlines`.

`File.readlines('log.csv').encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace).grep(/watch\?v=/)`

**' : undefined method `encode!' for # (NoMethodError)**

Whats the most straightforward way to filter/convert invalid UTF-8 characters during a File read?

<strike>**Attempt 1**</strike>

Tried this but it failed with same invalid byte sequence error.

```
IO.foreach('test.csv', 'r:bom|UTF-8').grep(/watch\?v=/).map do |s|
  # extract three columns: time stamp, url, ip
  s = s.parse_csv;
  { timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3] }
end
```

**Solution**

This seems to have worked for me.

```
a = File.readlines('log.csv', :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1').grep(/watch\?v=/).map do |s|
s = s.parse_csv;
{ timestamp: s[0], url: s[1], ip: s[3] }
end
puts a
```

[Does Ruby provide a way to do File.read() with specified encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664403/does-ruby-provide-a-way-to-do-file-read-with-specified-encoding)

Comment: Maybe it's a BOM issue and you can solve it by opening the files in `'r:bom|utf-8'` mode. Please try that.

Comment: @padde updated code with my attempt. thx

Comment: You should really be using CSV instead of File. That's what it's for.

Comment: @pguardiario yes, I looked at that initially. could you please provide an example to the alternative above. thx.

Comment: Next time post solution as an **Answer**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to get this solution working. I have seen people doing
>
> ```
>    .encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace)
> ```
>
> but it doesnt appear to work with File.readlines.

File.readlines returns an Array.  Arrays don't have an encode method.  On the other hand, strings do have an encode method.

> could you please provide an example to the alternative above.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("log.csv", encoding: "utf-8") do |row|
  md = row[0].match /watch\?v=/
  puts row[0], row[1], row[3] if md
end
```

Or,

```
CSV.foreach("log.csv", 'rb:utf-8') do |row|
```

If you need more speed, use the fastercsv gem.

> This seems to have worked for me.
>
> ```
> File.readlines('log.csv', :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
> ```

Yes, in order to read a file you have to know its encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the script defaulted to US-ASCII and I wasn't at liberty to change it on the server for risk of other conflicts.

I did

```
File.readlines(email, :encoding => 'UTF-8').each do |line|
```

but this didn't work with some Japanese characters so I added this on the next line and that worked fine.

```
line = line.encode!('UTF-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```