# Parsing json on ruby, arabic unicode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, arabic

I get json parse error on ruby code the article is on arabic because of :

```
JSON.parse(open('https://www.examlpe.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').read)
```

```
<p dir=\"rtl\">\u0623\u0639\u0644\u0646\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0643\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0637\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u0646\u0642\u0644 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0643\u0643 .<\/p>
```

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664403/does-ruby-provide-a-way-to-do-file-read-with-specified-encoding.  You might need to specify encoding when reading the string.

Comment: it's open uri not a file, and it's encoding is utf-8

Comment: Include the **exact** code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: And the **exact** error message please

Comment: the code is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution by remove the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

```
JSON.parse(open('https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts').read.gsub!("\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8"), '')
```