# How to write to get content from Google Cloud Storage in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to use the Google Cloud Function to retrieve the contents of a file placed in Google Cloud Storage?
Also, I would like to know how to do this.

I tried this,

```
 file = bucket.file(path)
 file.download.read
```

but I didn't read response

```
\xA3\xB4\x97..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = bucket.file(path)
downloaded_file = file.download
File.read(downloaded_file, encoding: 'ENCODE') # utf8 etc.
```

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11664569/7584295) answer.

GL.